# Download CPAN module distribution archive: I18N::Langinfo

Tags: perl

I am trying to download the module distribution archive for [`I18N::Langinfo`](https://metacpan.org/pod/I18N::Langinfo):

```
cpan -g I18N::Langinfo
```

which gives me a 14 megabyta file `perl-5.22.1.tar.bz2`. This archive contains 5633 files, where the subfolder `ext/I18N-Langinfo` contains the 4 files I am interested in.

Why do I get all the other files also? When I download a modules distribution archive I would expect to get the files in that distribution, I am not interested in the 5629 other files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I18N::Langinfo is a core module that isn't released separately on CPAN (i.e. it's not a "dual-life" module like Data::Dumper, for example). To get the source for the module, you have to get the entire Perl source tree.

See [perlsource](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsource.html#Core-modules):

> Modules shipped as part of the Perl core live in four subdirectories. Two of these directories contain modules that live in the core, and two contain modules that can also be released separately on CPAN. Modules which can be released on cpan are known as "dual-life" modules.
>
> ...
>
> - ext/
>
>   Like lib/, this directory contains modules which are only released as part of the core. Unlike lib/, however, a module under ext/ generally has a CPAN-style directory- and file-layout and its own Makefile.PL. There is no expectation that a module under ext/ will work with earlier versions of Perl 5. Hence, such a module may take full advantage of syntactical and other improvements in Perl 5 blead.